# import hibernate-orm source into eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gradle

I want to import hibernate source code into eclipse as a java project. I am new in this field and I'm stuck. I followed the instruction in https://community.jboss.org/wiki/BuildingHibernateORM4x5x. Installed git, downloaded the hibernate-orm. Next I did this `./gradlew eclipse` but got the following error.

```
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip

Unzipping /home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6-bin.zip to /home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:132)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

So I downloaded the gradle-1.6.bin.zip and copied it into the `/home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/` folder and ran the same command, this time I got this error

```
    Unzipping /home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6-bin.zip to /home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok
    Set executable permissions for: /home/souvik/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6/bin/gradle

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Failed to notify model configuration listener.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
       > Could not resolve org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.2.
         Required by:
             :buildSrc:unspecified
          > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.pom'.
             > peer not authenticated
          > Could not GET 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.pom'.
             > peer not authenticated
       > Could not resolve org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA.
         Required by:
             :buildSrc:unspecified
          > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.pom'.
             > peer not authenticated
          > Could not GET 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.pom'.
             > peer not authenticated

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 16.359 secs
```

I just want to know how do I import the git clone as a java project into my eclipse juno? I have tried to install m2eclipse plugin for eclipse, but it didn't work.

PS: I am in ubuntu 12.04 and I am inside a proxy firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to configure Gradle with your proxy settings, for example
`gradlew eclipse -Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`. For details see [Accessing the web via a proxy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: First problem is solved, but getting this build failed error message now. `A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hibernate-orm'.
> org/hibernate/build/gradle/publish/auth/maven/AuthenticationManager : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. It was due to mismatch in jdk and jre version. I had both jdk-6 and jdk-7 installed and default jre was pointing to jre-6 while default jdk was jdk-7. Uninstalled jdk-6 and it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I ran

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

The error is misleading `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` This gives the impression that version 51 (java 7) is not supported. And we should use Java 6.

The error should have been,

> Current java version 50 is unsupported, use Java version 7 (51:0 and greater)`